# Time Calculation Between Specific Events

Tags: r, date, time

Here is a subset of my data:

```
Fr         Sig  Code NumDet    Date.Time          Aerial
62  150102 102   15    195 2012-09-14 18:28:00      1
63  150102 102   15    189 2012-09-14 18:32:00      1
64  150102 106   15    213 2012-09-14 18:36:00      1
65  150102 102   15    152 2012-09-14 18:40:00      1
66  150102 105   15    190 2012-09-14 18:46:00      1
67  150102  97   15      4 2012-09-14 18:51:00      2
```

I am trying to calculate time between first detection on Aerial 1 and first detection on Aerial 2. Hence in this data set it would be 23mins

I have tried variations of `difftime` but can't seem to select specific times based on the Aerial number.

I have tried:

```
a <- difftime(table$Date.Time[2:length(table$Aerial == "1")], 
              table$Date.Time[2:length(table$Aerial == "2")])
```

but it's not even close.

Comment: What language are you using?  How are you reading this data?  Can you please post some of your code to review?

Comment: I am using R, the data is read in from a CSV file and Date.Time is as.POSIXlt with Aerial being numeric

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This command using `difftime`

```
difftime(table$Date.Time[table$Aerial == "2"][1],
         table$Date.Time[table$Aerial == "1"][1])
```

will return

```
Time difference of 23 mins
```

Comment: Thats great, thanks! didnt realise i was so close, i'm new to R... am i right in thinking the [1] selects the first time the aerial number occurs?   Thanks again!

Comment: What would you replace the '[1]' with the select the last element rather than the first? have tried 'length(x)' but wont work

Comment: @user1751379 You can select the last element of object `x` with the command `tail(x, 1)`. Using your example: `difftime(tail(table$Date.Time[table$Aerial == "2"], 1), tail(table$Date.Time[table$Aerial == "1"], 1))`